# How to change file group of TEXTIMAGE_ON

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to convert my DB to be Azure SQL V12 compatible which requires removing all file groups except for PRIMARY. I've migrated all PK and INDEXES to be on primary. Now I have only some tables that specified `TEXTIMAGE_ON` that are not in the primary file group. here is the current table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistLocation](
xxxx
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [HIST]
```

I tried doing the steps in this link: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/153-moving-sql-table-textimage-to-a-new-filegroup/

But when I try to save the file it states:

> "Saving changes is not permitted, The changes you made require the following tables to be dropped..."

Is there another way around this?

Comment: Is the error the smss nag screen warning message?

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly suggest that you use T-SQL to make changes, or at the very least, preview the scripts that the Designers generate before committing them. However, if you want to do this in the designer, you can turn off that lock by going to Tools...Options...Designers..Table and Database Designers.. and unclick the "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".

That lock is on by default for a reason; it keeps you from committing some change that is obfuscated by the designer.

EDIT: As noted in the comment below, you can't preview the changes unless you disable the lock. My point is that if you want to use the table-designer to work on a table with this feature disabled, you should be sure to always preview the changes before committing them. In short, options are:

BEST PROCESS: Use T-SQL
NOT GREAT: Disable the lock, use Table Designer, and ALWAYS preview changes
CRAZY TALK: Click some buttons.

Comment: I Would like to do this in T-SQL but i don't know how to generate the script properly this is why i was using the UI.